# Printing elements of a Dataframe Col - TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have run this code multiple times that reads thousands of .sed files and writes it to a .csv

Recently upgraded to Python 3.6.9 - not sure if that is the cause of the error

I have a dataframe and one of its columns is called 'Averages' and the example below shows the problem accessing the elements. I am not trying to access the elements to just print, but simplified the purpose for here.

```
for i in (df['Averages']):
    print(i)
```

Just checked and even the following gave the same error

```
df['Averages'].dtype
```

output error message:

`TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`

+++++++++++
df.head() works

```
df.columns 
MultiIndex([(     ' 340.0',),
            (     ' 341.0',),
            (     ' 342.0',),
            ...
            (      'T1[C]',),
            (      'T2[C]',),
            (      'T3[C]',),
            (   'DarkMode',),
            (  'Foreoptic',)],
           length=2172)
```

Comment: What does `type(df)` and then `type(df['Average'])` show you? It seems possible that `df` isn't actually a `DataFrame`...

Comment: type(df) gives pandas.core.frame.DataFrame but type(df['Average']) gives me the same error. Really frustrating since I ran this program hundreds of times before.

Comment: if it helps, I created the df like this : pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([time_list, average_list, other_list])

Comment: Okay... what does `df.columns` show you? And does `df.head()` work?

Comment: Please see the edits; I am not sure why it says MultiIndex since it isn't supposed to be MultiIndex

Comment: Are you sure that `time_list`, `average_list` and `other_list` are all 1D? That `column_stack` looks a little odd... Anyway... not sure how much help anyone else can be at the moment - now that you know what the issue is, since you've got the data and code - looks like a fun time debugging is in order :)